# Redirect Changed Permalink on wordpress

Tags: categories, permalinks

Please I recently changed my site permalink structure, from https://example.com/postname/ to https://example.com/category/postname/

I have searched online and even here but all I am seeing is /postdate/year/postname/ to /postname/

Since I have many categories I cannot make an htaccess 301 redirection for this, please is there any other way this can be done?

Comment: Are you a programmer? If so, yes this is possible. But you will need to invest some time to figure it out. If not, you should hire someone.

Comment: I dont know much on wordpress programming. Please kindly help out

Comment: Give this a shot: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda Usually you hook into `template_redirect` action for redirects. In your case it could be summarized as: check if the URL has a post slug, if that post slug exists in the db, redirect to the new permalink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have added new permalink structure by defining Custom Permalink Structure on

```
https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
```

and added **/%category%/%postname%/** in the **custom structure** field. This is the WordPress default/suggested method.

[image]

After this, you need to **flush** the old permalink structure by saving and **reloading** the permalink settings page.

This will not work for custom post type and only works for WordPress default post type. For custom post types you would have to apply additional hooks or defile it while [registering custom post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) function.

You should read the WordPress official documentation on [using permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/).

**Update:**

In this case, you can use "**404_template**" filter.

*Example*:

```
add_filter( '404_template', 'custom_redirect_to_category' );

function custom_redirect_to_category($template) {

    if ( ! is_404() ){
        return $template;
    }

    global $wp_rewrite;
    global $wp_query;

    if ( '/%category%/%postname%/' !== $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure ){
        return $template;
    }   

    if ( ! $post = get_page_by_path( $wp_query->query['category_name'], OBJECT, 'post' ) ){
        return $template;   
    }

    $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );

    wp_redirect( $permalink, 301 );
    exit;

}
```

Comment: I did exactly this, but my problem is to make a 301 redirect from the old permalink structure `/%postname%/` to the new one `/%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: I have updated my answer with the possible solution.

Comment: worked like charm, thanks alot

Comment: Glad It helped (Y)